# How to speed up Spotipy API calls for millions of records?

Tags: python, performance, spotify, spotipy

I'm attempting to get the audio feature data for about 4.5 years worth of Spotify Top 200 Charts. It's for 68 countries + global ranking, so about 20 million records in all. I'm querying a SQL Lite database with all of that data.
This is prep for a data analysis project and I've currently limited my scope to just pulling the 3rd Friday of every month because the fastest time I could get pulling an entire day's worth of audio features for the charts is 15.8 minutes. That's 18.5 days of straight processing to get all 1701 days.

***Does anyone see any way I could make this faster?*** I'm currently calling the *spotipy.audio_features()* function for each track id. The function is limited to 100 ids and I'm not so sure that would be much faster anyway.

Here's an example entry before processing:

```
column_names = ['title', 'rank', 'date', 'artist', 'url', 'region', 'chart', 'trend', 'streams']

('You Were Right', 179, '2017-01-20', 'RÜFÜS DU SOL', 'https://open.spotify.com/track/77lqbary6vt1DSc1MBN6sx', 'Australia', 'top200', 'NEW_ENTRY', 14781)
```

And after processing:

```
column_names = ['title', 'rank', 'date', 'artist', 'url', 'region', 'chart', 'trend', 'streams', 'track_id', 'danceability', 'energy', 'key', 'loudness', 'mode', 'speechiness', 'acousticness', 'instrumentalness', 'liveness', 'valence', 'tempo', 'duration_ms', 'time_signature']

('You Were Right', 179, '2017-01-20', 'RÜFÜS DU SOL', 'https://open.spotify.com/track/77lqbary6vt1DSc1MBN6sx', 'Australia', 'top200', 'NEW_ENTRY', 14781, '77lqbary6vt1DSc1MBN6sx', 0.708, 0.793, 5, -5.426, 0, 0.0342, 0.0136, 0.00221, 0.118, 0.734, 122.006, 239418, 4)
```

Full Script:

```
import sqlite3
import os
import spotipy
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
from requests.exceptions import ReadTimeout
from datetime import datetime

"""Gets the third Friday of each month and checks that the date exists in the database."""
def date_range_checker(cursor, start_date, end_date):
    # Put in the range for that year. It's till 2021.
    date_range = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date ,freq='WOM-3FRI')

    cursor.execute("""SELECT DISTINCT Date(date) FROM charts""")
    sql_date_fetch = cursor.fetchall()
    sql_dates = [r[0] for r in sql_date_fetch]

    validated_dates = []

    for date in date_range:
        # print(str(date)[0:-9])
        if str(date)[0:-9] in sql_dates:
            validated_dates.append(str(date)[0:-9])    
            
    return validated_dates

"""Connects to the database. For each date in validated_dates, it queries all the records with that date. 
Then splits the track IDs from the Spotify link into a new list of tuples. Then for each tuple in that list, it calls the Spotify API with the track ID.
Finally it creates a numpy array for the entire list so the csv converter can be used."""
def main(): 
    now_start = datetime.now()
    start_time = now_start.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    print(f'Main Function - start time: {start_time}')

    """"This script queries """
    print("working on it...")

    dbname = 'charts.db'

    if os.path.exists(dbname):
        db = sqlite3.connect(dbname, isolation_level=None)
        cursor = db.cursor()

        """"Selects 3rd friday of the month because it takes about 15.8 minutes per day. That's 14.2 hours total to get one friday a month for all 4.5 years.
        Or 18.6 full days of processing for every single day for all 1701 days.
         Fridays are a preferable release day in the industry. Cite this later."""

        # Date range list created and checked in this function
        validated_dates = date_range_checker(cursor, '2017-02-01', '2017-12-31') # change year here

        column_names = ['title', 'rank', 'date', 'artist', 'url', 'region', 'chart', 'trend', 'streams', 'track_id', 'danceability', 
        'energy', 'key', 'loudness', 'mode', 'speechiness', 'acousticness', 'instrumentalness', 'liveness', 'valence', 'tempo', 
        'duration_ms', 'time_signature']
        
        for date_chosen in validated_dates:
            cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM charts WHERE Date("date") = ?""", (date_chosen,))
            db_result = cursor.fetchall()

            data_with_track_ids = []
            final_data = []

            # Splits ID from Spotify link.
            for entry in db_result:
                track_id = entry[4].split('/')[-1]
                entry += (track_id,)
                data_with_track_ids.append(entry)

            print("I've got all the track IDs. Will start calls to Spotify API now.")

            # Calls to spotify with the new extracted track_id
            for entry in data_with_track_ids:
                track_id = entry[-1]

                try:
                    audio_features = spotify.audio_features(track_id)
                except ReadTimeout:
                    print('Spotify timed out... trying again...')
                    audio_features = spotify.audio_features(track_id)

                entry += (audio_features[0]['danceability'], audio_features[0]['energy'], audio_features[0]['key'], 
                audio_features[0]['loudness'], audio_features[0]['mode'], audio_features[0]['speechiness'], audio_features[0]['acousticness'], 
                audio_features[0]['instrumentalness'], audio_features[0]['liveness'],
                audio_features[0]['valence'], audio_features[0]['tempo'], audio_features[0]['duration_ms'], audio_features[0]['time_signature'])
                
                final_data.append(entry)

            np_data = np.array(final_data)
            my_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(np_data, columns=column_names)
            my_dataframe.to_csv(f'spotify_csv_data/spotify_top_200 {date_chosen}.csv')

            now_end = datetime.now()
            end_time = now_end.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            print(f'Main Function - Start time: {start_time}. End time: {end_time}.')
            print(f'The date {date_chosen} took {now_end - now_start} to run.')
            

    db.close() 



if __name__ == "__main__":
    now_start = datetime.now()
    start_time = now_start.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    print(f'Script - start time: {start_time}')


    os.environ['SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID'] = 'ENTER YOUR CLIENT_ID'
    os.environ['SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET'] = 'ENTER YOUR CLIENT_SECRET'

    # Allows for retries. Seems to be enough that it doesn't crash.
    spotify = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=SpotifyClientCredentials(), requests_timeout=10, retries=10) 
    """Leave above set."""
    
    main()

    now_end = datetime.now()
    end_time = now_end.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    print(f'Script - Start time: {start_time}. End time: {end_time}.')
    print(f'This script took {now_end - now_start} to run.\n')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profile, profile, profile.  But the bottleneck is likely soptify's api.  Whilst you can parallelise to speed up fetching, they won't thank you much for it and you will likely find yourself rate limited if you do it too much.  So profile and see *what* is taking the time, but be prepared to cut back on your dataset.

Ask yourself what you can do to speed up the *algorithm*:

- can you just fetch the top N hits?
- do you really need all that data?
- is any data duplicated?

Even if data *isn't* duplicated, create a local cache, indexed by the track_id, and store every request in that.  Rather than requesting from the spotify endpoint, look it up in the cache (store the data in another sqlite database, or another table in the same db). If nothing is returned, fetch, save the data to the cache, and then return it.  That way:

- if you *are* doing redundant lookups, it will be faster.
- even if you aren't, you can re-run your code blazingly fast (at least as regards your current speed) if you change something and need to run the lot again.

So cache, profile, and look at your algorithm.

Comment: Sorry for not responding. Thanks for your help. I ended up only querying unique values and calling those from Spotify's API. Worked out to be much, much faster.

Comment: @robotpsychology glad you got it going.  Algorithmic speedups normally far outrank machine speedups.

Answer (score 2):

A few ideas to improve performance:

1. Use parallel processing

Since you are using Python, the code running is single threaded.

Using Python's [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) library, you could (for example) run 4 instances of the same code but with evenly divided start/end dates.  This can make your data processing ~4x faster. You would just need to write the data in such a way that there is no overlap.

Note: If you are rate limited by the Spotify API (you most likely will be), you can use different API keys for each instance. (Make multiple accounts or borrow a friends API key).

2. Sql query optimizations

It's worth looking into your queries to see what is going wrong.  I'm personally not familiar with SQL, just giving you ideas.

3. Profile your program to understand more.

See [How can you profile a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script)

4. Use some sort of caching technique to avoid redundant api calls and to avoid populating duplicate data. (See a potential solution below, in last block of code using `ids_seen`)

python3

```
# Splits ID from Spotify link.
for entry in db_result:
    track_id = entry[4].split('/')[-1]
    entry += (track_id,)
    data_with_track_ids.append(entry)
```

In this code, what type is entry?  How big is db_result?

Another thing worth mentioning regarding your following code:

python3

```
# Calls to spotify with the new extracted track_id
for entry in data_with_track_ids:
    track_id = entry[-1]

    try:
        audio_features = spotify.audio_features(track_id)
    except ReadTimeout:
        print('Spotify timed out... trying again...')
        audio_features = spotify.audio_features(track_id)

    entry += (audio_features[0]['danceability'], audio_features[0]['energy'], audio_features[0]['key'], 
    audio_features[0]['loudness'], audio_features[0]['mode'], audio_features[0]['speechiness'], audio_features[0]['acousticness'], 
    audio_features[0]['instrumentalness'], audio_features[0]['liveness'],
    audio_features[0]['valence'], audio_features[0]['tempo'], audio_features[0]['duration_ms'], audio_features[0]['time_signature'])
    
    final_data.append(entry)
```

In the try-except block, you are making a request for every entry in `data_with_track_ids`. How many elements in the `data_with_track_ids` data structure?  Expect to be throttled and timed out by Spotify servers if you brute force api calls.

You should add a short wait period after timing out to reduce chances
of getting rate-limited or IP banned. Oh wait, looks like when you initialize the spotify variable, the retries are set and handled automatically under the hood in spotipy source code.

**EDIT**

Here is a way you can avoid making redundant requests by using Python's set data structure. This can serve as your "cache":

```
# Calls to spotify with the new extracted track_id
ids_seen = set()
for entry in data_with_track_ids:
    track_id = entry[-1]

    if track_id not in ids_seen:
        try:
            # retries are already built-in and defined in your __main__(), spotify variable
            audio_features = spotify.audio_features(track_id)
        except SpotifyException as se:
            print('Spotify timed out...Maximum retries exceeded...moving on to next track_id...')
            print("TRACK ID IS: {}".format(track_id))
            print("Error details: {}".format(se))
            ids_seen.add(track_id)
            continue
        # on success, add track id to ids seen
        ids_seen.add(track_id)
    else:
        print("We have seen this ID before... ID = {}".format(track_id))
        continue # skips the next 5 instructions and starts again at top of loop, next iteration

    entry += (audio_features[0]['danceability'], audio_features[0]['energy'], audio_features[0]['key'], 
    audio_features[0]['loudness'], audio_features[0]['mode'], audio_features[0]['speechiness'], audio_features[0]['acousticness'], 
    audio_features[0]['instrumentalness'], audio_features[0]['liveness'],
    audio_features[0]['valence'], audio_features[0]['tempo'], audio_features[0]['duration_ms'], audio_features[0]['time_signature'])
    
    final_data.append(entry)
```

If you are limited to 1000 req/day, then simply sleep program for 24 hours or stop program (and save current iteration and data context), and run again after you are allowed more requests.
See https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/guides/rate-limits/

Comment: The idea of parallel processing is interesting, but I think that spotify will limit his requests in this case

Comment: @Ofir Different API key for each instance would solve that

Comment: I'm going to try multiprocessing with multiple API keys and get back to y'all. There's an example entry in the post that shows the tuple that entry returns. db_result varies because of missing days in the records but it should typically be about 13,800 tuples.

Comment: @robotpsychology see edit update, I don't know exactly how many requests Spotify will limit you.  This is your main bottleneck. Youtube for example limits to 100 requests per day for free search api. Of course, if you need more bandwidth, Spotify has a form on their website to request for more. Idk if its free

Comment: but *build a cache first*, since there are redundant requests here

Comment: @2e0byo see edit update, I added code to handle redundant requests. Using track_id as the cache key. The set data structure will serve the role of cache here. Print statements will let OP know which ids are problematic or duplicates

Comment: I would persist that set to disk as json at the end of the run, and try to load it first. (that is, if you don't just store it in the same db the OP is already using).

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `spotify.audio_features(track_id)` for every single track, even if you've already fetched its data. Each Friday's results should only introduce a few new songs, but you're re-fetching information on all 200. Don't do that. Make another database table for song info. After you've fetched a `track_id`'s info, write it to the database. Before fetching a `track_id`'s info, see if you've already stored it in the database. Then you'll only be making the bare minimum of necessary API calls, rather than 200 * num_weeks * num_countries.